# How to skip 0 radius which create cords error

Tags: python, shapefile, buffer, fiona

I am new in Python and I have to do program that make buffers around cities in shp file. My problem is how to skip 0 radius? It makes coords error. I think I should use a continue function but I don't have any idea where.

```
import fiona

from shapely.geometry import mapping, shape

with fiona.open('file.shp', 'r') as input:
    schema= { 'geometry': 'Polygon', 'properties': { 'name': 'str', 'population' : 'int' } }
    with fiona.open(
        'result.shp', "w", "ESRI Shapefile", schema, "epsg:4326" ) as output:
        for point in input:
            output.write({
                'properties': {
                    'name': point['properties']['NAME'], 'population': point ['properties']['POP_MAX']
                },
                'geometry': mapping(shape(point['geometry']).buffer(point['properties']['POP_MAX']/1000000))               
            })
```

Comment: Okay, I don't know Python but doesn't it support an if statement? If pop_max != 0 buffer-then-write-geometry. It looks like you should check the pop_max value first before going into the write function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to skip cities that have a population less than 1 million, just compute the buffer size before writing the feature. That will give you an opportunity to check if the feature should be written.

```
import fiona

from shapely.geometry import mapping, shape

with fiona.open('file.shp', 'r') as input:
    schema= { 'geometry': 'Polygon', 'properties': { 'name': 'str', 'population' : 'int' } }
    with fiona.open(
        'result.shp', "w", "ESRI Shapefile", schema, "epsg:4326" ) as output:
        for point in input:
            buffer_size = point['properties']['POP_MAX']/1000000
            if not buffer_size: # if buffer_size == 0:
                continue
            output.write({
                'properties': {
                    'name': point['properties']['NAME'], 'population': point['properties']['POP_MAX']
                },
                'geometry': mapping(shape(point['geometry']).buffer(buffer_size))               
            })
```

If you want cities with populations less than 1 million, use float division instead of integer division.

```
import fiona

from shapely.geometry import mapping, shape

with fiona.open('file.shp', 'r') as input:
    schema= { 'geometry': 'Polygon', 'properties': { 'name': 'str', 'population' : 'int' } }
    with fiona.open(
        'result.shp', "w", "ESRI Shapefile", schema, "epsg:4326" ) as output:
        for point in input:
            buffer_size = point['properties']['POP_MAX']/1000000. #float
            if not buffer_size: # if buffer_size == 0:
                continue
            output.write({
                'properties': {
                    'name': point['properties']['NAME'], 'population': point['properties']['POP_MAX']
                },
                'geometry': mapping(shape(point['geometry']).buffer(buffer_size))               
            })
```